# Signup creating user, but getting error 'Invalid format string'

Tags: python, django

Struggling to figure out what's wrong with my signup view/serializer.

When I signup, a new user is created, however I get the error message:

```
Invalid format string
```

with a `500 internal Server Error` message

this is my api endpoint:

```
path('api/register', RegisterApi.as_view()),
```

This is my RegisterApi:

```
class RegisterApi(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    #remove this if it doesn't work
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "message": "User Created Successfully.  Now perform Login to get your token",
        })
```

and this is my RegisterSerializer:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.CharField(source='profile.city', required=False)
    country = serializers.CharField(source='profile.country', required=False)
    profile_pic = serializers.ImageField(source='profile.profile_pic', required=False)
    is_online = serializers.BooleanField(source='profile.is_online', required=False)
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(source='profile.is_active', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        #removed url from fields
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'country', 'profile_pic', 'is_online', 'is_active']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
        def create(self,validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                                            username=validated_data['username'],
                                            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                            email=validated_data['email'])
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            #added fields from profile
            user.profile.city = validated_data['city']
            user.profile.country = validated_data['country']
            user.profile.bio = validated_data['bio']
            return user
```

Upon further investigation the exception seems to have something to do with a datetime field . This is the full traceback:

```
Exception Location: C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py, line 1242, in to_representation

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = await sync_to_async(response_for_exception, thread_sensitive=False)(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
    else:
        @wraps(get_response)
        def inner(request):
            try:
                response = get_response(request)
…
            except Exception as exc:
                response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
        if response is None:
            wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
            # If it is an asynchronous view, run it in a subthread.
            if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(wrapped_callback):
                wrapped_callback = async_to_sync(wrapped_callback)
            try:
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
…
            except Exception as e:
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
                if response is None:
                    raise
        # Complain if the view returned None (a common error).
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py, line 54, in wrapped_view
def csrf_exempt(view_func):
    """Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection."""
    # view_func.csrf_exempt = True would also work, but decorators are nicer
    # if they don't have side effects, so return a new function.
    def wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
…
    wrapped_view.csrf_exempt = True
    return wraps(view_func)(wrapped_view)
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py, line 69, in view
            self = cls(**initkwargs)
            self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
            if not hasattr(self, 'request'):
                raise AttributeError(
                    "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "
                    "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__
                )
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
…
        view.view_class = cls
        view.view_initkwargs = initkwargs
        # __name__ and __qualname__ are intentionally left unchanged as
        # view_class should be used to robustly determine the name of the view
        # instead.
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 509, in dispatch
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc)
…
        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response
    def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 469, in handle_exception
        exception_handler = self.get_exception_handler()
        context = self.get_exception_handler_context()
        response = exception_handler(exc, context)
        if response is None:
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
…
        response.exception = True
        return response
    def raise_uncaught_exception(self, exc):
        if settings.DEBUG:
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    def raise_uncaught_exception(self, exc):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            request = self.request
            renderer_format = getattr(request.accepted_renderer, 'format')
            use_plaintext_traceback = renderer_format not in ('html', 'api', 'admin')
            request.force_plaintext_errors(use_plaintext_traceback)
        raise exc
…
    # Note: Views are made CSRF exempt from within `as_view` as to prevent
    # accidental removal of this exemption in cases where `dispatch` needs to
    # be overridden.
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py, line 506, in dispatch
            # Get the appropriate handler method
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
…
        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc)
        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\signup\api.py, line 19, in post
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
…
            "message": "User Created Successfully.  Now perform Login to get your token",
        })
    # #allow for anonymous signup
    # def get_permissions(self):
    #     if self.action == 'create':
    #         return [AllowAny()]
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py, line 555, in data
        return BoundField(field, value, error)
    # Include a backlink to the serializer class on return objects.
    # Allows renderers such as HTMLFormRenderer to get the full field info.
    @property
    def data(self):
        ret = super().data
…
        return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)
    @property
    def errors(self):
        ret = super().errors
        if isinstance(ret, list) and len(ret) == 1 and getattr(ret[0], 'code', None) == 'null':
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py, line 253, in data
                'You should either call `.is_valid()` first, '
                'or access `.initial_data` instead.'
            )
            raise AssertionError(msg)
        if not hasattr(self, '_data'):
            if self.instance is not None and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
                self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
…
            elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
                self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
            else:
                self._data = self.get_initial()
        return self._data
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py, line 522, in to_representation
            #
            # For related fields with `use_pk_only_optimization` we need to
            # resolve the pk value.
            check_for_none = attribute.pk if isinstance(attribute, PKOnlyObject) else attribute
            if check_for_none is None:
                ret[field.field_name] = None
            else:
                ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
…
        return ret
    def validate(self, attrs):
        return attrs
Local vars
C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py, line 1242, in to_representation
        value = self.enforce_timezone(value)
        if output_format.lower() == ISO_8601:
            value = value.isoformat()
            if value.endswith('+00:00'):
                value = value[:-6] + 'Z'
            return value
        return value.strftime(output_format)
…
class DateField(Field):
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _('Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: {format}.'),
        'datetime': _('Expected a date but got a datetime.'),
```

Comment: add the error trace to the question

Comment: @mohamednaser I added the full trace

Answer (score 0):

Took a cursory look at your code and have not carefully looked at it. So may be I am not right in my suggestion.

May be you are one indentation too deep for the create method.

Instead of this.

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.CharField(source='profile.city', required=False)
    country = serializers.CharField(source='profile.country', required=False)
    profile_pic = serializers.ImageField(source='profile.profile_pic', required=False)
    is_online = serializers.BooleanField(source='profile.is_online', required=False)
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(source='profile.is_active', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        #removed url from fields
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'country', 'profile_pic', 'is_online', 'is_active']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
        def create(self,validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                                            username=validated_data['username'],
                                            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                            email=validated_data['email'])
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            #added fields from profile
            user.profile.city = validated_data['city']
            user.profile.country = validated_data['country']
            user.profile.bio = validated_data['bio']
            return user
```

you can try this

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.CharField(source='profile.city', required=False)
    country = serializers.CharField(source='profile.country', required=False)
    profile_pic = serializers.ImageField(source='profile.profile_pic', required=False)
    is_online = serializers.BooleanField(source='profile.is_online', required=False)
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(source='profile.is_active', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        #removed url from fields
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city', 'country', 'profile_pic', 'is_online', 'is_active']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
    def create(self,validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
                                        username=validated_data['username'],
                                        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
                                        last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
                                        email=validated_data['email'])
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        #added fields from profile
        user.profile.city = validated_data['city']
        user.profile.country = validated_data['country']
        user.profile.bio = validated_data['bio']
        return user
```

Comment: Getting the error:
`'Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'first_name'` when I try this